# txt2las to change the format from ASCII to LAS

Tags: lastools

I am working on many files with the format (.asc), I am trying to change the format to LAS/LAZ but for some reason only 8 files from 42 files have been successfully changed for the others the error is "was not able to find header"

This is an example of my data:

```
ncols         485
nrows         390
xllcorner     780734,05409779
yllcorner     4432728,2630359
cellsize      8
NODATA_value  -9999
112,925 112,9903 113,1189 113,2021 113,4172 113,4973 113,5752 113,7636 113,8014 113,6562 113,5051 113,2463[....]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post one good and one bad file.